# Updating Redux state does not trigger componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: redux

I'm trying to validate the login information. After making sure the login is valid I want to fire a new route.
I pass the state.loginReducer.login as props. When I handle the submit event, an action is dispatched, changing the global login state.

Shouldn't `ComponentWillReceiveProps` be fired in this case? since the props changed?. Is there a better way to implement this functionality?

```js
handleSubmit (evt) {
    const {
        dispatch,
        login
    } = this.props;

    dispatch(actions.doLogin(value.login));
}

ComponentWillReceiveProps (nextprops) {
    const {
        login
    } = this.nextProps;

    if (login != null) {
        history.pushState({}, '/account');
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        login: state.loginReducer.login
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: The obvious solution would be using a callback (that's what I'm doing right now), but I'm still not sure about CWRP not being fired in this case.

Comment: Are you defining `mapStateToProps` as a class method? Make sure that you're not accidentally passing in `undefined ` to connect.

Answer (score 33):

If `state.loginReducer.login` changes, then `componentWillReceiveProps` will get triggered. If you believe your reducer is returning a new state, and `componentWillReceiveProps` is not being triggered, make sure that the new state is immutable. Returning the same state reference thats passed to the reducer won't work.

From https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md

This is wrong:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_TODO':
    // Wrong! This mutates state
    state.push({
      text: action.text,
      completed: false
    });
  case 'COMPLETE_TODO':
    // Wrong! This mutates state[action.index].
    state[action.index].completed = true;
  }

  return state;
}
```

This is right:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_TODO':
    // Return a new array
    return [...state, {
      text: action.text,
      completed: false
    }];
  case 'COMPLETE_TODO':
    // Return a new array
    return [
      ...state.slice(0, action.index),
      // Copy the object before mutating
      Object.assign({}, state[action.index], {
        completed: true
      }),
      ...state.slice(action.index + 1)
    ];
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is dead on. In my case the issue was I was doing this -- `return Object.assign(state, { key: newValue });` -- instead of this -- `return Object.assign({}, state, { key: newValue });`. The trick here is that starting `Object.assign` with the old object updated THAT object, as opposed to returning something new, so Redux seems to have thought that nothing changed, even though the data of the object did (because the identifier remained the same).

Comment: @Sasha thanks, your comment actually helped me. I was creating a new object with same keys. One of the keys contained an array that was mutated, but actually was a reference to an old array from previous state.

Comment: In my case I'm definitely doing this your right way but CWRP is not getting triggered. Before my asynch change the previous CWRP shows `this.state` and `nextState` both in the old state and following the change the next CWRP shows both in the new state. I never see `this.state` with the old state and `nextState` with the new.

Comment: Please have look on this question , i will appreciate your help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152672/render-function-not-getting-call-after-dispatching-action-from-component

Answer (score 12):

```
ComponentWillReceiveProps (nextprops)
```

should be

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextprops)
```

The `C` should be lower case. Actually, `mapStateToProps` triggers `componentWillReceiveProps`. I'm sure about that.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

```js
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        login: Object.assign({}, state.loginReducer.login),
    }
}
```

For making sure the object return is actually `new`.