# Updating redux state doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm working on an app at the moment and although I'm facing the same issue as here, [Updating Redux state does not trigger componentWillReceiveProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322068/updating-redux-state-does-not-trigger-componentwillreceiveprops).

I've read through this answer and am not mutating the state and I can see the different state when I log in mapStateToProps, but my componentWillReceiveProps is not being fired.

My code is as follows:

```js
const mapReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_MARKER':
      return action.selectedMarker;
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default mapReducer

    //mapActions.js

export const setMarker = (selectedMarker) => {
  //Used to set the one that the user has selected.
  return {
    type: 'SET_MARKER',
    selectedMarker
  }
}

    //InformationScreen.js

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('returning in mapStateToProps');
  console.log(state.mapReducer);
  //Here I see that state.mapReducer is different everytime.
  return {
    marker: state.mapReducer,
    user: state.userReducer,
    completed: state.completedReducer
  }
}

class InformationScreen extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      //No logs in here.
      console.log('Receiving props and the marker is');
      console.log(nextProps.marker);
  }

  render() {
    const { marker } = this.props;
    console.log(marker);
    // Here the marker does update.
    return(<Text> Hello world </Text>);
  }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InformationScreen);

import app from './reducers';
let store = createStore(app);

export default class App extends React.Component {

      state = {
        isLoadingComplete: false,
      };
    
      render() {
        if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
          return (
            <AppLoading
              startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
              onError={this._handleLoadingError}
              onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
            />
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <ActionSheetProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <View style={styles.container}>
                {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
                {Platform.OS === 'android' &&
                  <View style={styles.statusBarUnderlay} />}
                  <RootNavigation />
              </View>
            </Provider>
            </ActionSheetProvider>
          );
        }
      }

}

//index.js

    import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
    import mapReducer from './mapReducer'
    
    const app = combineReducers({
      mapReducer,
      //other reducers
    })
    
    export default app


//Dispatching the action from


    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { setMarker } from '../actions/mapActions';
    import { Container, Header, Tab, Tabs, TabHeading, List, ListItem, Left, Thumbnail, Body, Separator, Badge, Right} from 'native-base';
    import _ from 'lodash';
    
    import GLOBALS from '../constants/Globals';
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        user: state.userReducer,
        challenges: state.allChallengesReducer
      }
    }
    
    class MyChallengesScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'My Challenges',
        headerTintColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(77, 90, 139, 1)'}
      };
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.handleRefresh();
      }
    
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.user.facebookId) {
          this.handleRefresh(nextProps);
        }
      }
    
      constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          refreshing: false,
        }
      }
    
      markerPressed = (marker) => {
        //setChallenge.
        marker.coordinate = {latitude : +marker.latitude, longitude: +marker.longitude};
        console.log('Setting the marker');
        this.props.dispatch(setMarker(marker));
        this.props.navigation.navigate('InformationScreen');
      }
    
    
      render() {
        return (
          <Button onPress={() => this.markerPressed()}></Button>
        )
      }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MarkersScreen);
```

I hope someone else has seen something similar to this before. Thanks in advice for any help with this.

Edit: So unfortunately I still haven't been able to solve this yet. But I have found something pretty interesting when using the Redux debugger. componentWillReceiveProps is called when after dispatching the action I then 'skip' that action. Seems pretty strange, but at least it's something. Time to continue digging.

Comment: How do you add the `mapReducer` to your store?

Comment: Just editing the question now.

Comment: you can use componentWillUpdate which will give you callback while change state in redux store

Answer (score 3):

`connect` will shallow compare the output of `mapStateToProps` to the previous output of `mapStateToProps`. If there are no changes, it will not re-render the connected component, i.e. `InformationScreen`. As you said that you are "definitely mutating the state" the shallow compare will find no difference between the outputs of `mapStateToProps`.

You can override this behaviour of avoiding re-render by passing in the correct options. `connect` accepts `options` as the 4th argument, which is an object for which you will need to set `pure: false`.

refer to https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

> [pure] (Boolean): If true, connect() will avoid re-renders and calls to mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, and mergeProps if the relevant state/props objects remain equal based on their respective equality checks. Assumes that the wrapped component is a “pure” component and does not rely on any input or state other than its props and the selected Redux store’s state. Default value: true

Comment: Oops thanks, indeed should be not mutating the state :D

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer should only return a new object representing the state (not mutating the current state).
Your reducer should look like this

```
const mapReducer = (state = {selectedMarker: null}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_MARKER':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        selectedMarker: action.selectedMarker
      });
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

`Object.assign` mutates the first argument by adding all attributes that exist in all arguments after. Meaning it will mutate the `{}` by first adding the attributes in `state` then adding the attribute `selectedMarker: action.selectedMarker`. If `state` already has a `selectedMarker` then that will be overwritten in the new object.

and in your `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    marker: state.mapReducer.selectedMarker,
    ...
  }
}
```

**Object Mutation**
With the console logs showing different values after `mapStateToProps` problem is that you cannot visually tell if it's one mutated object or not. What is happening in `connect` is that new `marker` prop is tested for strict equality (`===`) against previous `marker` prop. Thing is that it doesn't matter how does the object look like, what properties it has etc. Only thing that is checked is if the object reference is the same

https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions

https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#note-on-object.assign

Comment: Could you please explain for me, and others reading this, how I'm mutating the state currently. I don't see it.

Comment: In my opinion it seems like mine are your code is doing the exact same thing, but instead in my code I return the marker directly and you return an object {selectedMarker: marker}, where marker is what I return.

Comment: As I thought this doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Certainly! You are returning `action.selectedMarker`. Meaning the selectedMarker will be your new state, which is not something you want. Redux can explain it better https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#note-on-object.assign

Comment: It doesn't help? Strange. Could you update your question by adding the code where you add your mapReducer to the store?

Comment: Indeed. Additionally I made a note saying that in render when I do const { marker } = this.props; it is different each time?

Comment: Yep will do that now.

Comment: It is still a bit  hard to reproduce. How and where are you dispatching the action? Are you using Redux-Thunk?

Comment: Will add the code where I'm dispatching the action too.

Comment: Are you using Redux-Thunk?

Comment: No, I'm not actually. Still not able to see anything wrong here unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the information but I am stumped as I cannot see what is wrong. I hope that you figure out the solution and post it when you are done but I'm afraid I cannot help anymore than what I already have said. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is here:

```
 markerPressed = (marker) => {
    //setChallenge.
    marker.coordinate = {latitude : +marker.latitude, longitude: +marker.longitude};
    console.log('Setting the marker');
    this.props.dispatch(setMarker(marker));
    this.props.navigation.navigate('InformationScreen');
  }
```

You are modifying the *existing* marker object, and dispatching an action to put that into the store.  The reducer simply returns the marker object it was given.

We always emphasize that *reducers* need to be pure functions that update data immutably, but you actually need to create your new data immutably *wherever you are creating it*.  If you have a reducer that just does `return action.someValue`, then the logic that *created* `someValue` needs to create it immutably.

So, for your case, your `markerPressed()` class method needs to make a *copy* of the marker and give it a new coordinate value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, have been searching all day and looking over the same code and SO. Just to be clear, the marker that is being passed into this function here, isn't the one that was previously in the redux store. It's actually a 'marker' that I retrieved from my web api and put in a list, what I'd like to do is select the element in the list, and then in the Information screen to know which 'marker' I pressed I've stored the 'marker' in the redux store.

Comment: Do you mean that I should do something like this in markerPressed. 1. Create a new object such as, suggested by @srdjan Object.assign({}, state, {selectedMarker: action.selectedMarker}), and then pass that into the setMarker action? I will give it another go.

Comment: No, I don't think it's the reducer that's the issue.  In your `markerPressed()` function, where is `marker` actually coming from?

Comment: The marker in `markerPressed()` comes from another screen, where allMarkers is a prop. I then loop over the allMarkers and create a list item for each, where the onPress prop is the call to `markerPressed()`.

Comment: Okay, and what is the ultimate source of the data in that screen?  Did it come from the Redux store?

Comment: Yes, they came from an API call then from the redux store.

Comment: Yep.  So, the data flow is:  Redux store -> mapState -> component -> class method _where you are mutating the object that come from the store_ -> action creator -> reducer -> put it right back into the store.  You're directly mutating the object that's in the store - don't do that :)

Comment: Aha! I see! So you can't mutate anything that comes from the state. I understand now, I'm going to give it a go. Thanks so much for the help. Fingers crossed it works, I'll put up the answer for other people afterwards if it helped. :)

Comment: So in markerPressed() I just need to create a new object and copy over the values to that new object, and then carry on with the flow from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wow! I'm glad to say the issue has been fixed. It seems that the reason was that, since InformationScreen is in a StackNavigator, a new instance is created every time. Since the first time an object is created componentWillReceiveProps isn't called, this explains it. Additionally T
thanks to @markerikson, for pointing out that I should be recreating a marker object with each action dispatch. Thanks again, and so happy to be able to get back to work! It's probably a rookie error.

Reference: https://shripadk.github.io/react/tips/componentWillReceiveProps-not-triggered-after-mounting.html